# Running the app in standby

Tags: android

Is it possible that the app can run a method when the phone is on standby. If I get a new signal via Bluetooth I want to run a method even if the phone is on standby. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an intentService? Also you'll need a broadcast Receiver registered in the app's manifest in order for it to start the service in the background. What kind of signal do you wish to receive?
Hope this helps: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Comment: A Bluetooth signal

Comment: Okay, then you need to know what kind of intent is sent (if any, there are some bluetooth actions that sent specific intents) when the signal you want is received and add that action to the intent filter.

Comment: I just get a String with the value

Comment: You can try to run a new thread in the service listening to the inputstream and start the service in the onDestroy method... im not sure this is the best way to do it tho